# How to place comma separated values within braces and again separated by comma

Tags: c#, jquery, sql

From user I will get the Input is in the form of `(1, 21, 2, 7, 6,16)`
but I want to Pass value in the form of `((1),(21), (2), (7), (6),(16))` to sql.

So, Can anyone suggest me a method to parse this values either in JQuery or in c# code.

Comment: is  (1, 21, 2, 7, 6,16)  string or array or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are being passed a string of "1, 21, 2, 7, 6, 16" and looking for a way to convert that to a string of "(1), (21), (2), (7), (6), (16)", then you could do the following (in c#)

assuming your input is in the variable foo:

```
        var foo = "1, 21, 2, 7, 6, 16";
        var numbersWithPotentialSpaces = foo.Split(',');
        var numbers = numbersWithPotentialSpaces.Select(x => x.Trim());
        var numbersWithParens = numbers.Select(x => "(" + x + ")");
        var newString = string.Join(", ", numbersWithParens);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var szData="(1, 21, 2, 7, 6,16)";
    szData = szData.replace("(","");
    szData = szData.replace(")", "");
    szData = szData.replace(/,/g, "),(")
    szData = "((" + szData + "))"
    console.info(szData)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample how to do this in C#:

```
var input = "(1, 21, 2, 7, 6,16)";
var array = input
    .TrimStart('(').TrimEnd(')')  // Trim symbols ( and )
    .Split(new char[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) // Split into array, removing empty entries
    .Select(x=>x.Trim())        // Trim spaces from the number
    .Select(x=>string.Format("({0})", x));  // Select each item in format (x)
    var result = string.Format("({0})", string.Join(", ", array));  // create result
    // result is    ((1), (21), (2), (7), (6), (16))
```